# Exclude a file in a directory from apache .htaccess password protected site

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have password protect my application directory but for some reason i have to give a public access to a file in a folder. i research and tried many ways but its not working. Following is my code.

```
# Welcome to your htaccess file.
# Remember that modifying this file can break the entire website
# so please edit carefully.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cms
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cms/index.php/$1 [L]

<IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv CI_ENV production
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"

AuthUserFile /home/root/.htpasswd
require valid-user

# allow public access to the following resources
#SetEnvIf Request_URI "(folder/)$" allow
#SetEnvIf Request_URI "(path/folder\file.php)$" allow-Uri

# Deny by default 
# Order deny,allow
# Deny from all

Order allow,deny
#Allow from env=allow-Uri

<Files "path\to\file.php">
  Allow from all
</Files>

Satisfy ANY
```

My project folder structure is as follow:

```
root-folder
--sub-folder
  --file.php
```

ScreenShot:
https://ibb.co/R9j0QTW

Comment: `Allow`/`Order`/`Deny`/`Satisfy` are deprecated. If you have Apache >= 2.4, `Require env allow-Uri` should work (`<RequireAny>` block is implicit here). (after fixing your pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it should be done:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/path/to/file\.php" ALLOW_URI

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /home/root/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Satisfy    any
Order      deny,allow
Deny from  all
Allow from env=ALLOW_URI
```

Comment: the popup with username and password arise same way for whole application.

Comment: domain.com/root-folder/sub-folder/file.php?abc=123

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218148/discussion-between-mubin-and-anubhava).

Comment: Your attached screenshot shows a different URL but you have different one for `ALLOW_URI` in .htaccess

Comment: sorry posted wrong screenshot. here is a correct one https://ibb.co/R9j0QTW @anubhav

Comment: Change `SetEnvIfNoCase` line to this: `SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/(helpdesk/ticket\.php|cms/index\.php)" ALLOW_URI`

Comment: https://ibb.co/jkPwRww its not working @anubhav. Do i have to check some apache settings??

Comment: once again I don't see my suggested block of code at top. Also for test just keep this much code in .htacess and test